Prevent Jupyter screen from jumps down after cell evaluation - but still select next cell
Whenever i evaluate a cell (Shift+Enter) jupyter moves the screen down so that the output is no longer on my screen. I find this feature rather annoying as it jumps so fast that i sometimes lose track where i was.
Is there a way to modify this behavior or to disable automated screen adjustments entirely?
I found this: Prevent Jupyter screen from jumps down after cell evaluation
But I still want the next cell to be selected, I just don't want the screen to jump, only when the cells are off screen do i want the bar to scroll down
tried: Prevent Jupyter screen from jumps down after cell evaluation
